# To fetch Random/different records each time

Tags: mysql, random

I have 3 thumbnails which i want to rotate each time a user refresh the page. Therefore want to show different thumbnail each time. I have image name stored in the database. I am using this SQL query to fetch "select thumbnail from tablename order by rand() limit 1". It is fetching one thumbnail perfectly.

The problem is that sometime same images comes up. For example first time i refresh the page thumbnail 1.jpg shows but second time again 1.jpg comes up.

So what i am looking for is to have different thumbnail each time i refresh the page.

Can anyone provide me some suggestions to achieve this ?

Comment: The pronoun "I" is capitalised in English, and you should accept some previous answers please.

Comment: Okay, Aleks, Will do from now on. Thanks

Comment: First off, selecting a "random" row and selecting a different row each subsequent query are two different tasks.  Try to be more clear with your question.  Second, what language are you implementing the mysql connection in?  It might be best to store a persistent variable (session?) using this language.  Lastly, people are going to be less inclined to answer your questions if you have yet to accept an answer in any of the questions you've asked.

Comment: Jeff, i have a gallery with image name, description and thumbnail. So the row will be totally different when we fetch the random record. I am using PHP with MySql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible with random selection, as the same image can come again.

For the effect you want you need to use a cookie to store the last displayed image name and NOT display that image for the next request.

As you have confirmed in your comment you do not want to display the last displayed thumbnail. IN that case you can do this like this using `sessions`:

```
// get last shown from session if any
$last_shown = '';
if(isset($_SESSION['last_shown_thumb']))
    $last_shown = $_SESSION['last_shown_thumb'];

// select a thumbnail randomly which is not the one last shown
$query = "SELECT thumbnail FROM tablename WHERE thumbnail <> '" . $last_shown . "' order by rand() limit 1";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$curr_thumb = $row[0];

// set the current to last shown in session
$_SESSION['last_shown_thumb'] = $curr_thumb;
```

Comment: Thanks Danish, however i have plenty of thumbnails. It's a gallery so i don't think it is feasible to save each and every image name in cookie. there can be about 50-70 thumbnails on a page.

Comment: @Zack You only dont want to display the last one again right? in that case you only need to store the one last displayed. IF you dont want to show ANY of the previously shown , you can store it in a server side array using `sessions`.

Comment: yeah, that's true i don't want to show the last one. I can store them  in session as well however i think it will not be feasible to store 50-70 thumbnail names in sessions and then show others after comparing with already saved thumbnails in session. Don't you think it will make site slow to load ?

Comment: @Zack I have updated my answer with a code sample. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using PHP, you store the previous thumbnail in `$current_thumbnail`. 
Then, you can do it like this

```
SELECT thumbnail FROM tablename WHERE thumbnail <> '$current_thumbnail' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Your query just needs to know what thumbnail you are currently displaying so you can filter it out.

Comment: Actually, i have a gallery to show can have 50-70 thumbnails on a single page. Is it feasible to store all those in various variables or in a array ?

Comment: If this particular table has an primary key (`id` maybe), you can store that in an array instead so your statement will be like `$sql = "SELECT id, thumbnail FROM tablename WHERE id NOT IN (".implode(',',$id_array).") ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1"`. I guess you'll have to get the id too so you can store that in an array.

Comment: Don't you think saving 50-70 thumbnails in a array and then query it like this slow the site to load ?